# mysql : table don't exist error on table creation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

slm, HI
can you help me please !
my problem is when i create a new table named : `fiche_med` like this:

`create table fiche_med(id int(10) primary key not null)` on MYSQL i have that message error :

`#1146 - Table 'test.fiche_med' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) well
the solution is that you have to remove all `views` using a table witch have same name (i hade a table named `fiche_med` that i removed) as your new table and then restart your MYSQL server

Answer (score 1):

what you have to do is just move database files to new location and update mysql server. All tables with InnoDB engine would disappear from my database. If you try to recreate them, mysql would show an error 1146: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist all the time until you recreate the database and restart mysql service.

Comment: Can you provide links and other related questions to backup this statement? This seems a very far fetch